# getting error in php to login in google account using openid.php

Tags: php, authentication, openid, lightopenid

I am using `openid.php` in php to authorize by Google account.
but it will show `9` warning like

```
Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in C:\xampp\htdocs\CuePointExample3\openid.php on line 315

Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]: Failed to enable crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\CuePointExample3\openid.php on line 315
```

and so on.

Comment: are you using LightOpenID or not ? if so you are confusing people with openid.php , and past all the errors , not just the first ones.

Comment: [get_headers()](http://php.net/get_headers) is a built-in PHP function. I suspect your system is missing some required libraries or needs extra configuration. If you print the URL and call `get_headers()` in a test script you'll probably be able to reproduce the issue and hopefully find a fix.

Comment: now i am getting error No OpenID Server found at https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id